# Display only first, second and last children using nth-child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to display only the first, second and last children using nth-child?

What will be the algebraic expression?

I'm not able to figure this out, even after using CSS selectors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this with multiple [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class

```css
ul li:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)):not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about a single algebraic expression, but you can group selectors into a single rule.

```css
li { display: none; }

li:first-child,
li:nth-child(2),
li:last-child {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
```

OR

```css
li { display: none; }

li:nth-child(-1n + 2),
li:last-child {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>random</li>
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Show your items only when either of the following applies :

- `:nth-child(-n+2)` (first + second item)
- `:last-child` (last item)

---

#### Demo

```css
li {
    display: none;
}

li:nth-child(-n+2), li:last-child {
    display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```